# CENTOS 7: Running mysqldump without user/password in shell but errors

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

I would like to run the bash script in CentOS 7 in terminal to export database dump. However, it ends with error.

**backup_test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

thisthing=fiveminute
dumpfile=db-${thisthing}-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.sql
mysqldump database_name > $dumpfile.tmp 
mv $dumpfile.tmp $dumpfile
```

I have setup my ~/.my.cnf to be able to run dump without asking for user password:

**.my.cnf**

```
[mysqldump]
user=username
password=password
skip-extended-insert
skip-dump-date
```

**Execution from terminal**

```
[site.backup@localhost ~]$ ./backup_test.sh
```

This ends up in following error:

```
-bash: ./backup_test.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please guide where I am going wrong??

**Edit #1**

Permissions are set properly as backup_test.sh is set to be executable

**Solution**

The problem was due to the Windows based line endings, \r, guess I copied the script from Windows based file into the Centos file, hence the error.

To change the script from Windows encoding to Unix in `vim` you could also use `:set ff=unix` and then save the file, or `:set ff=dos` to get DOS formatting again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have windows end of line characters (`\r`) in your shebang line (that's the `^M`) part.  Run `dos2unix` on your script and you should be good.

If you don't have `dos2unix` the following will work with GNU sed (should be default on CentOS 7):

```
sed -i 's/\s*$//' backup_test.sh
```

which will remove the whitespace (including `\r`) from the end of each line, so don't do this if there is important whitespace at the end of lines (which does not seem to be the case with your script)

Comment: how do I run dos2unix on script?

Comment: @GhazanfarMir run `dos2unix backup_test.sh` then just run `backup_test.sh` as normal

Comment: I get this error: bash: dos2unix: command not found...

Comment: @GhazanfarMir see my update for an alternate solution

Comment: Thanks Eric - I managed to do that using the VIM: